# remote connect to RHEL with X server from Windows

Tags: rhel, x11

I have remote RHEL 7 server.
I have Windows laptop.
I want to connect to RHEL with UI (X Server). (So far I only have ssh connection using Putty.)

What tool should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to display X (client) applications you should consider the [Xming X server for windows](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/).

If you want to be able to use the RHEL desktop you can either use a remote desktop based protocol. You will have to [enable this on your server](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Desktop_Deployment_Guide/ch-ddg-remote-desktop.html) (and that is assuming it has the Desktop packages installed).

Another approach is installing a virtual machine manager and run Linux in a VM on your Windows laptop (assuming it is not 15 years old and its performance/memory is enough to do so). That gives you an X server both for running remote programs on the server and for local applications. (At some point you might want to switch and run windows as VM under Linux).

Comment: What is the difference between "just display X(client) applications" and "able to use the RHEL disktop"? I want for example to run Eclipse on RHEL and see UI on my Windows PC. Currently i'm able to do this via HP iLO.

Comment: @javapowered The difference is in the way you start things. If you don't have a remote desktop, the only way to start an application is use the commandline. For Eclipse Xming should be enough, but e.g. the resize buttons on the windows will be different as running native.

Comment: thanks, what about `x2go`?

Comment: @javapowered never used that. Looks ok, and seems to ahve  Fedora support.

Comment: i've tried xming, it works